# AMD A10-5700 work out of the box?

Tags: 12.04

If the CPU, AMD A-Series A10-5700 quad-core processor with AMD Radeon HD 7660D, that is the internal graphics card Radeon HD 7660, from Ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit) out of the box work?

Answer (score 0):

[The openbenchmarking.org page here](http://openbenchmarking.org/s/AMD%20A10-5700%20APU) suggests that it does. From personal experience, I can only say that an A10-5750M worked with 12.04 and 13.10 for me - the latter combination is what I am now typing on.

As with all Ubuntu distributions, there will be a fair bit of googling and command-line work involved in configuring the machine optimally.